# MYSQL 'NOT IN' statement with group_concat( table_name ) from information_schema.tables

Tags: mysql

in my table 'entites' i store some tablenames in column 'tablename' of the used database.
Now i want to get all tablenames of the database who are not in entites.tablename

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'codeigniter'
AND table_name COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT IN (
    (SELECT concat(tablename) FROM codeigniter.entities)
)
```

This works fine, but i'm not shure that this is th best practice:

My database and all tables and columns has 'utf8_unicode_ci' collation, 
the information_schema has 'utf8_general_ci' collation.

structur of table 'entites' in database codeigniter :

```
(
    `id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tablename` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 
AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery returns a single concatenation string of all* tables in the "codeigniter" schema; unless you expect entities.table to be such a concatenation, you won't get the results you want.

It is the difference between `A IN ("B", "C", "D")` AND `A IN ("B,C,D")`

**"ALL" as in all that the setting for the max length of a group_concat call will allow to fit.*

My guess is you simply need to not use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your table structure, but try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT entities FROM entities.table WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM t2 WHERE table_schema = 'codeigniter')
```

Source: [mysql SELECT NOT IN () -- disjoint set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246462/mysql-select-not-in-disjoint-set)